# use two ASIHTTPRequest in the same class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

if i use ASIHTTPRequest the first time , with asynchroun mode , i recive result and error in

> - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
>     and the error in
> - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

but what if I make another query asynchronously? I will receive the result in the same method? how to know if this is the result of the first query or second? I tryed to change the delegate but it don't work

```
-(void)getCities
{
    NSString * myURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8080/Data/resources/converter.city/CountryCode/%@",choosedCodeCity];

    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:myURLString];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:resultCities];
    [request startAsynchronous];


}

-(void)resultCities :(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
request.didFinishSelector = @selector(yourFinishMethodHere:);
request.didFailSelector = @selector(yourFailMethodHere:);
```

in other words, you do not have to use the default "requestFinished:" and "requestFailed:" methods on the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

ASIHttpRequest has a `NSDictionary* userInfo` property that you can use to store whatever you like.  You can simply add a flag to this dictionary in order to tell the two requests apart.

Another approach would be to use the ASIHttpRequest methods that take blocks instead of using a delegate.

**EDIT:**
To use the flag approach, when you create the request object, do something like

```
[request.userInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"flag"];
```

Then in the response methods you can ask the request for the flag to determine which request it is.

```
int flag = [[request.userInfo objectForKey:@"flag"] intValue];
```

Comment: thank you but I am a beginner, I do not think I really understood. You speak about tag ? i don't thik that i should use blocks , there is too much treatment of the two queries and I want to separate them

Comment: Added more info about the flag approach